# Excel 2010 how can I calculate percentile of numbers in a column only if there is a specified number in a different column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Please forgive me but I'm at best a good intermediate excel user.  I'm trying to calculate call time data for fire department responses organized by station number.

column c is station number and column L is the times.  I need to calculate 0.9 percentile of column L only if column C is 27.

I know it's a nested formula starting with =PERCENTILE( but from there that is where I can't seem to find the right path.  I have tried if, ifs, countif, vlookup and a few others.  can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks all.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do an array formula `=PERCENTILE.INC(IF(C:C=2,l:l),0.9)` and then hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTR to enter the formula

Comment: I wans putting " " around the 27 which is why it wasn't working.  thank you so much.  I now need to take it one step further.  just as above but I need to filter it by number in C like before and then any of 4 or 5 different numbers in B (111,113,118).  would that use ifs?

Comment: =PERCENTILE.INC(IF((C:C=27)*(B:B=111)+(C:C=27)*(B:B=113)+(C:C=27)*(B:B=118),L:L),0.9)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the percentile for the line that you are working on, simply change C=2 to c=c2.  I'm assuming that you are working in row 2.  This will change the percentile answers to be relevant to the station in that row.

In other words, lets say column M is your 'Percentile' column.  In M2, you input the array formula

```
      =PERCENTILE.INC(IF(C:C=C2,L:L),0.9)
```

Then, as you copy down the column, it will give you the percentile information for the station number in that row.  For example, say 27 is in row 2.  M2 gives percentile information for station 27.  Say 111 is in row 3.  M3 gives information on station 111.  Make sense?